# How to deploy application on JoNaS in a Docker container

Tags: maven, unix, jenkins, docker, jonas

I am using Docker (Unix system) in order to make containers where I can deploy some web applications (made in Java). I installed and configured properly JoNaS in one of this container but I am missing something about the networking.

In fact, the thing is that I use a Jenkins job which call some Maven (maven-cargo-plugin more precisely) in order to deploy in the container (rmi:// protocol).

I guess they cannot discuss properly because the containers aren't on the same network. I am actually not allowed to change anything of the network settings so I search a solution which bypass bridges or something like that.

If they aren't any, does you guys have an idea for my problem ? I made a little draw about my configuration if you guys think I was not clear enough (http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/209383DockerExp.png).

Although, sorry for my English mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to expose the Cargo port from the Docker container so that Jenkins can connect to the Docker host IP on that port to get into the container. See http://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#expose-incoming-ports for usage. For example, if the Cargo port was 6767, you might run the container with `-p 6767:6767` which would allow Jenkins to connect to port `6767` on the Docker host IP (same network).

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I already know that and have mapped the right port used by Cargo in order to deploy sucessfully my EAR on the Jonas instance but something is wrong because the log tell me that I am pointing on the wrong IP address (the container IP)
In fact, I am having a java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 172.17.0.232; nested exception is: [...]
I really don't know what I am doing wrong...